# Link string to existing array name

Tags: python

I'm looking to link a string to an existing array. Below is the idea I'm going for

```py
Fruits = [apples, bananas, cherries, grapes]
Veggies = [Broccoli, Peas, Corn]

def main(Variable, Number): 
     output = vars(Variable)[int(Number)] # similar to Veggies[1]
     print(output) # The output should be peas
 

main('Veggies', '1')
```

This is just altered from what I have, same principle though.

Comment: While I could use if-then statements, there will be quite the amount of arrays and would be cleaner if I could just go this route.

Comment: edit post to add additional information, also those are `list`s not arrays

Comment: Use a dictionary.

Comment: Are the contents of `Fruits` and `Veggies` actual variables, or are they strings you forgot to surround in quotes?

Comment: Not really knowing the real scope of your problem, a simple solution would be to store these lists as the values of a `dict` and then map names to them, e.g. `{ "Fruits": [ "apples", "bananas", ... ] }`, and then you can do stuff like `return the_dict[Variable][Number]`.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi They are actual Variables. I'm looking to link the two names.

Comment: @wkl That may work, I can try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Variable variable names" is a major anti-pattern and is something to always avoid. Instead use Dictionaries:

```
Food = {'Fruits':['Apples','Bananas','Cherries','Grapes'],'Veggies':['Broccoli','Peas','Corn']}

def main(Variable, Number): 
     output = Food[Variable][int(Number)]
     print(output) # The output should be peas
 

main('Veggies', '1')
```

---

```
Peas
```

Comment: It looks like `apples`, `Broccoli`, etc. are variables ([not strings that OP forgot to quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73114258/link-string-to-existing-array-name?noredirect=1#comment129131235_73114258)), so a dict of dicts would be the correct data structure

Comment: `{"Fruits": {"Apples": apples, "Bananas": bananas, ...}, ...}`, although that changes the access logic in `output = ...` slightly

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I think OP just fat fingered and didn't add quotes to their strings, but otherwiseI would agree.

Comment: @JNevill I thought so too and I asked them to clarify, which they did in the comment I linked above